# Axios - [Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Request failed with status code 404]

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, axios, yelp

I'm trying to connect to the yelp api using axios on a React Native application, but I'm getting the above mentioned error: Here's the full version:

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Request failed with status code 404]
- node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:15:17 in createError
- node_modules\axios\lib\core\settle.js:16:9 in settle
- node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\xhr.js:52:6 in handleLoad
- node_modules\event-target-shim\dist\event-target-shim.js:818:39 in EventTarget.prototype.dispatchEvent
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:566:23 in setReadyState
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:388:25 in __didCompleteResponse
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\vendor\emitter\EventEmitter.js:190:12 in emit
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:436:47 in __callFunction
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:111:26 in __guard$argument_0
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:384:10 in __guard
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:110:17 in __guard$argument_0
* [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

I'm creating axios instance in yelp.js file:

```
export default axios.create({
  baseURL: "https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search",
  headers: {
    Authorization:
      "Bearer uBsNGAyIv1M66CWgKUxdIITOmc7Z9oYzngUVVlVgUCaqFx-mARcKkw24hm6lecWq2jNAgU2s045rASW4o-_mTFCRcDZ0Z8732gd-hjRbayRf0u2NUHsZK6O5PCVZXnYx"
  }
});
```

I've already made sure that the API key added into the Authorization is correct.

I'm trying to call/render yelp api (using GET request) in a separate SearchScreen.js file:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import SearchBar from "../components/SearchBar";
import yelp from "../api/yelp";

const SearchScreen = () => {
  const [term, setTerm] = useState("");
  const [results, setResults] = useState([]);

  const searchApi = async () => {
    const response = await yelp.get("/search", {
      params: {
        term,
        limit: 50,
        location: "karachi"
      }
    });
    setResults(response.data.businesses);
  };
  return (
    <View>
      <SearchBar
        term={term}
        onTermChange={newTerm => setTerm(newTerm)}
        onTermSubmit={() => searchApi()}
      />
      <Text>Search Screen</Text>
      <Text>We have found {results.length} results.</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});

export default SearchScreen;
```

What is the issue here? Whenever I try to initiate a search with a term on the screen, this is popping up as a warning and I'm unable to return any results at all.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Do you know what [404](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404) means?

Comment: for some reason YELP is retrieving nothing for your query. 404 simply means it couldn't find what you are looking for. Make sure to catch the failure and then send results of 404 to your user(s) as well. unless you are 100% certain that there needs to be result then I would say you need to look at how you are requesting your data from yelp. Additionally, you can manually query yelp and see if that returns any results.

Answer (score 4):

You are sending an invalid URL, because of that error `404` displayed.

In your Axios instance you are setting your base path as

```
https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search
```

When you call that instance, you are appending your base path with `"/search"` as below,

```
await yelp.get("/search", {params: {term, limit: 50, location: "karachi"}})
```

Now your url looks like

```
https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search/search?....
```

So remove `/search` from Axios instance.

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.

Answer (score 2):

One thing is your error. It tells you that you should catch your potential promise rejection.

```js
const searchApi = async () => {
  try {
    const {data} = await yelp.get("/search", {params: {term, limit: 50, location: "karachi"}})
    setResults(data.business)
  } 
  catch (err) {
    console.warn(err)
    setResults([]);
  }
};
```

This will prevent your program from stopping. You still have to figure out why you get your 404 code.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem until i restarted my react native project using:

```
expo start -c
```

For the beginners , the `-c` just deletes all the chache and rebuilds the project from scratch

Comment: This worked for me, I closed Vscode and then restarted the frontend and backend servers and it worked like a charm. All attempts to stop and restart both servers gave errors until I saw this and implemented it. Thanks for sharing this solution